# On the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations, solution-verification

Here is a what I did which is the same as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), but with more details:

Given a set $X$ with an equivalence relation ${\sim}$

> There exist a bijection between the set of all possible partitions of $X$ and a set of all equivalence relations on $X$:

The relation between these two sets is [$\color{blue}{\text{left-total}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) since for every quotient set $X/{\sim}$ there exist a partition containing all equivalence classes of $X$ by ${\sim}$.

Also the relation is [$\color{blue}{\text{functional}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) and  $\color{green}{\text{injective}}$ since for every $X/{\sim}$ there exist just a **unique** partition containing all elements of $X/{\sim}$ (because if not , then there exist a $X/{\sim}$ which is mapped to **more than one** partition, so the partitions should be equal but there does not exist any two partitions with the same elements, a contradiction) and the same can be said for two quotient set of $X$ mapping to a single partition  .

Since each partition is identical to one $X/{\sim}$ therefore the relation between the two sets is $\color{green}{\text{surjective}}$ .

Finally we've shown that the relation between these two sets is a $\color{green}{\text{bijective}}\: \color{blue}{\text{function}}$

Is my proof right?

Comment: It's colorful and seems convincing, but the essence is hidden here. You should explicitly define the correspondence.

Comment: @Berci, you are right! but can you help me a little?

Comment: It's easy and implicitly you already used it. If an equivalence relation $\sim$ is given, what partition does it induce? Conversely, given a partition, how do you define an equivalence relation?

Comment: @Berci, well of an equivalence ${\sim}$ is given, then it does induce to a unique partition $P$ , and conversely given a partition $P$ the equivalence relation ${\sim}$ can be defined via the set of all elements contained in the cells of the partition $P$

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. But can you write up formulas?

Comment: @well I guess no,( if you mean the formula for the number of partitions over a set well I can use Stirling numbers and derive the nth Bell number using Dobinski’s Formula), but if you don't mean that, then is it possible to edit/ complete my proof in a post?, it would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I meant only the correspondence. $\Phi(\sim) :=\{\{a:a\sim x\} \ :\, x\in X\} $

Comment: @Berci, well I know that, but how it will help me to edit my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set.

Let $\mathcal P$ denote the collection of all partitions on $X$.

Let $\mathcal E$ denote the collection of all equivalence relations on $X$.

Then you assert that a bijection $\mathcal P\to\mathcal E$ exists.

You start with a relation which is in this context a subset of $\mathcal P\times\mathcal E$ but do not really mention which relation you have in mind here.

If $R$ denotes the relation then for proving that it is a bijection it is indeed necessary and sufficient to show that:

- $R$ is left-total, i.e. for every $P\in\mathcal P$ there is at least one $E\in\mathcal E$ such that $(P,E)\in R$.
- $R$ is functional, i.e. for every $P\in\mathcal P$ there is at most one $E\in\mathcal E$ such that $(P,E)\in R$.
- $R$ is injective, i.e. for every $E\in\mathcal E$ there is at most one $P\in\mathcal P$ such that $(P,E)\in R$.
- $R$ is surjective, i.e. for every $E\in\mathcal E$ there is at least one $P\in\mathcal P$ such that $(P,E)\in R$.

A relation having these properties is exactly a bijection.

The only thing missing is an explicit definition this relation.

This can be repaired by stating that: $$(P,E)\in R\iff P=\{[x]_E\mid x\in X\}$$where $[x]_E$ denotes the equivalence class wrt $E$ that is represented by element $x\in X$.

Or alternatively by stating that:$$(P,E)\in R\iff E=\{(x,y)\in X^2\mid\exists p\in P[x,y\in p]\}$$

Then the bullet points can be proved one by one.

IMV however it is more handsome to define functions $f:\mathcal P\to\mathcal E$ and $g:\mathcal E\to\mathcal P$ and to prove that $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are both identities. This assures that $f$ and $g$ are bijections.

Let $f$ be prescribed by:  $P\mapsto\{(x,y)\in X^2\mid\exists p\in P[x,y\in p]\}$.

Let $g$ be prescribed by: $E\mapsto \{[x]_E\mid x\in X\}$.

It is not difficult to prove that $f(P)\in\mathcal E$ for every $P\in\mathcal P$ and $g(E)\in\mathcal P$ for every $E\in\mathcal E$ showing that we are indeed dealing with functions $f:\mathcal P\to\mathcal E$ and $g:\mathcal E\to\mathcal P$.

Also it is not difficult to prove that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are identities.

Comment: So since $\text{Id_$\mathcal P$}$ is bijection implies $g$ is surjection and $f$ is injection, Since  $\text{Id_$\mathcal E$}$ is bijection, implies $g$ is injection and $f$ is surjection, and hence both of them are bijection, therefore there exist a bijection between the two sets. am I right? also is $p$ a cell in $P$? and what is this notation $P[x,y\in p]\}$?

Comment: Correct. If $g\circ f$ is an identity then $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, and similar story for $f\circ g$. If $P$ denotes a partition and $p\in P$ then $p$ is one of the sets of this partition. The notation $P[x,y\in p]$ on its own makes no sense. You should read $\exists p\in P[x,y\in p]$. In words: "there exists an set $p$ belonging to partition $P$ such that $x,y$ are both element of that set."

Comment: Actually Berci (author of the other answer) also uses functions. They are named $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ there and the two compositions are both identities. So what I am saying is not more or less as what he says in his answer.

Comment: we showed that $f$ and $g$ are both bijective(relation) but you say "It is not difficult to prove that $f(P)\in\mathcal E$ for every $P\in\mathcal P$ and $g(E)\in\mathcal P$ for every $E\in\mathcal E$ showing that we are indeed dealing with functions" . well why even need to show that they are functions? as long as we know they both are bijective relations it would be enough .

Comment: I said that because I intended to introduce a new approach (functions instead of relations) and forgetting on purpose everything said before about relations.

Comment: Of course I will accept your answer, because it's **really** complete, and the reason I still have not is because the lack of my knowledge (sorry for that), so is there any problem if I use the second approach without mentioning that the relation is actually a function?(in my opinion the result still follows )

Comment: I think even for the first one showing that there exist a bijective relation between them is enough (although in my post I proved that the relation is a function)

Comment: Proving that relation $R$ is a function is actually the same as proving that relation $R$ is left-total and functional. This corresponds with proving that $f$ is a function. Proving that relation $R^{-1}$ is a function is the same as proving that relation $R$ is injective and surjective. This corresponds with proving that $g$ is a function. In essence there is not really a difference between the two (relations, functions) approaches.

Comment: is there anything named "bijective relation"?, or a bijective is always a function?

Comment: If the terminology is used (I do not exclude that) then very rarely. I never encountered it. Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481694/75923) is interesting to look at.

Comment: Where Wikipedia wants to prove the fundamental theorem of equivalence classes  it uses the terminology "bijection" which is a **bijective function** , in this way you say "It is not difficult to prove that $f(P)\in\mathcal E$ for every $P\in\mathcal P$ and $g(E)\in\mathcal P$ for every $E\in\mathcal E$ showing that we are indeed dealing with $\color{red}{functions}$" , so besides showing " $f(P)\in\mathcal E$ for every $P\in\mathcal P$ and $g(E)\in\mathcal P$  for every $E\in\mathcal E$" (which meaning besides showing the **left-totality**) we also need to show it's **functional**, am I right?

Comment: if we do that, hence we showed in both approaches that we have a **bijective functions** between the two sets, although I think we still can show in both approaches that there exist a **bijective relation** between the two sets without showing it's functionality

Comment: I don't know what a bijective relation is (and do not feel any urge to find out), but it would not surprise that in essence it is exactly the same thing as a bijective function. That would also explain why the term is rarely used. We already have a well-known alternative for it: bijection or bijective function. Read the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482039/75923).

Comment: I got it, and if I just show the left-totality and functionality of the second approach then everything will be alright (notice that you already showed it's  bijective)?

Comment: Yes. If a relation $R$ is left-total and functional then that relation is a function. If this function is shown to be bijective then you are ready. The function is bijective if and only if $R^{-1}=\{(y,x)\mid (x,y)\in R\}$ is also a function. Or equivalently if and only if $R$ is injective and surjective. In the first approach the first two bullets state that $R$ is a function and the third and fourth state together that $R^{-1}$ is a function.

Comment: many thanks for your patience and for your effort to help me (+1)

Comment: We have maintained a bijective relation for a while :-). Thank you.

Comment: One last thing: I edited and enlarged the sentence "...that we are indeed dealing with functions $f$ and $g$.." to: "...that we are indeed dealing with functions..$f:\mathcal P\to\mathcal E$ and $g:\mathcal E\to\mathcal P$.." This because *not* the question whether $f$ and $g$ are *functions* was at stake here, but the questions: does $f$ has indeed have $\mathcal E$ as codomain? and does $g$ has indeed $\mathcal P$ as codomain?... My point was that the answer on these question is "yes" and is not difficult to prove. I realize now that this can have been the cause of confusion on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is basically fine, but the correspondence should be explicitly given:

$$\Phi(\sim) :=\{\{a:a\sim x\} \ :\, x\in X\} \\
\Psi(\mathcal S) :=\{(x,y) :\exists S\in\mathcal S:\, x,y\in S\}$$
Once these are given, (after verifying that $\Phi(\sim)$ is a partition if $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and that $\Psi(\mathcal S)$ is an equivalence relation if $\mathcal S$ is a partition), it's easier to simply check that
$$\Psi(\Phi(\sim)) =\sim \\
\Phi(\Psi(\mathcal S)) =\mathcal S\,. $$