# Theorem related to canonical projection

Tags: equivalence-relations

Given a set $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$, define quotient mapping $\pi:X \to X/\sim$, it's known the canonical projection is surjective and this fact follows from definition of equivalence class and the symmetric property of $\sim$.

Theorem:

> Define $f:\small X \to B$ such that for every $a,b \in X$ if $a \sim b$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$, then there exist a unique function $G:\small {X/\sim} \to B$,  such that $f = g\pi$. If f is a surjection and $a \sim b ↔ f(a) = f(b)$, then $g$ is a bijection.

If $f$ is surjective then so is $g$, form where the injectively of $g$ follows?and why $g$ is **unique**?

Also what is the application of this theorem?

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is unique because it is determined by $[x]\mapsto f(x)$ where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class represented by $x$.

If $h$ would do the same then $h([x])=f(x)=g([x])$ for every $x$ hence $h=g$.

---

$g$ is injective because $g([x])=g([y])$ implies that $f(x)=g([x])=g([y])=f(y)$ or equivalently $x\sim y$ or equivalently $[x]=[y]$.

---

Application of the theorem...

Well, it appears that by surjective $f:X\to B$ there is no essential difference between $X/\sim$ (with elements $[x]$) and $B$ (with elements $f(x)$) and no essential difference between $f$ and $\pi$. We can mark $f$ as a quotient function, just like the canonical $\pi$. It is a good thing to have a bright view on that.

Comment: You say $[x]\mapsto f(x)$, clearly by definition of function ( left-totality) for every $[x]$ in $X/\sim$ there exist a $g([x])$ such that $[x]\mapsto g([x])$, but how do you know $g([x])=f(x)$?

Comment: $g([x])=f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ is exactly the statement that $g\circ\pi=f$.

Comment: Also you say $f(x)=f(y)$ or **equivalently** $x \sim y $ but by definition of $f$ we have $a \sim b$ **implies** $f(a)=f(b)$ and not vice versa, so how..?

Comment: I read in your question: "...If $f$ is a surjection and $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$". So two sides. Btw, if it would not be two sides then how is $\sim$ defined?...

Comment: The link I've seen the theorem is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation , do you think the direction should holds for the other side? (if yes so there is an error in Wikipedia)

Comment: If we only have $a\sim b\implies f(a)=f(b)$ then the proof in my answer concerning uniqueness of $g$ is still valid. It rests completely on $g([x])=f(x)$ and I do not use the other side there. For injectivity we need more (this is also clear on Wikipedia).

Comment: so how injectively of $g$ can be proven?

Comment: Injectivity requests the other side. Nowhere in your question it is asserted that there is also injectivity if the other side lacks. Actually it is about uniqueness of $g$ and secondly bijectivity of $g$ and the condition given for bijectivity are: "$f$ is surjective **and** $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$."

Comment: For instance let it be that $a\sim b\iff a=b$. Then $X/\sim=\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$ and $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto[x]=\{x\}$. Evidently $a\sim b\implies f(a)=f(b)$ and $g$ is the function prescribed by $g(\{x\})=f(x)$. If in that situation $f$ is not injective then also $g$ is not injective. This shows the necessity of the other side for $g$ being injective.

Comment: @Thank you, I don't have the book that this question comes from and it appears that Wiki is wrong. can you do me a favor and look at this post of mine? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525445/on-the-fundamental-theorem-of-equivalence-relations

Comment: Is there still something that withholds you from accepting my answer? Please let me know.