# Bijective-like mapping that is not a functon

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let's have a <s>mapping</s> relation $M$ between two sets. If $M$ is a function then we can check if it is injective and surjective. Is it valid to talk about these properties also if $M$ is not a function?

Example.

$A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{a,b,c\}$, $M=\{(1,a),(1,b),(2,c)\}$.

Injectivity: $\forall y \in B: (x_1,y) \in M \land (x_2,y) \in M \Longrightarrow x_1 = x_2$

Surjectivity: $\forall y \in B \; \exists x \in A: (x,y) \in M$

So, could be $M$ called a bijective <s>mapping</s> relation? Does any other more appropriate term exist?

EDIT: In original question I used the term "mapping" but I wanted to describe relations.

Comment: Well, a bijective mapping from what to what?  What two sets do you think are put into bijection by $M$?

Comment: Could be M called a bijective mapping from A to B?

Comment: I believe that a relation from $A$ to $B$ is both injective and surjective if and only if the inverse relation from $B$ to $A$ is a function. A nice exercise in definitions! But I wouldn't call a relation a "mapping" if it's not a function (and indeed it would typically confuse people to call non-functions "injective" or "surjective").

Comment: Thanks. It  is my English I did not use the term mapping correct. I was talking about relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is not a mapping at all. Rather, it's a **relation** satisfying some but not all of the defining properties of bijective mappings.

A relation between two sets $X$ and $Y$ is just any subset of $X\times Y$. There are a few important properties of such relations:

- $R\subseteq X\times Y$ is **functional** iff $(x,y),(x,y')\in R\implies y=y'$.
- $R$ is **total** iff for each $x\in X$ there is at least one $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$.
- $R$ is **injective** iff $(x,y),(x',y)\in R\implies x=x'$.
- $R$ is **surjective** iff for each $y\in Y$ there is at least one $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in R$.

Note that functionality is the "dual property" to injectivity, and totality is similarly dual to surjectivity. The relation $M$ you describe is total, injective, and surjective, but not functional.

Comment: Thanks. It is my English I did not use the term mapping correct. I was talking about relations.

Comment: So, relation that is both injective and surjective is not valid to be called bijective?

Comment: Btw, [there is at least one reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849874/386889) for these definitions.

Comment: I asked the question on my own, but now I can see similar definitions elsewhere.

Comment: @AnneBauval - Thanks for the reference. I was thinking "makes sense, but I've never heard those terms used like that". I guess they are.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Me too, whence my effort.